# FB.getLoginStatus returns a session even after the user has logged out of Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is driving me crazy. A user logs into my Facebook app, does some stuff. Then goes to Facebook and logs out. I've got a little timer that calls FB.getLoginStatus() every once in a while to see if the user is still logged in. But whenever FB.getLoginStatus() gets called it returns a response with a session object. WTF? Shouldn't it return undefined/unknown?

I'm using the absolute most basic call to Facebook evar:

```
FB.init({
    appId: 'MY APP ID',
    cookies: false,
    status: true,
    xfbml: false
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.session) {
        console.info("Session exists");
    } else {
        console.info("Session empty");
    }
});

setInterval(function () {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.session) {
            console.info("Session exists");
        } else {
            console.info("Session empty");
        }
    });
}, 10000);
```

I checked and double checked the permissions that are being requested with the allow. I am only requesting email and sms. So.... any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initializating FB with

```
status: false
```

So it will work as you expect. It worked for me

Answer (score 6):

don't do it in the hard way. This situation has a simple solution, just add a "**true**" statement as a second parameter from the ***getLoginStatus*** method:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
   if (response === undefined || response.status === 'connected') {
      // Do something after logout
   }
}, true);
```

Just be careful and aware that every call to this function will make your App to go to Facebook's servers and can give you a considerable amount of network load depending on your implementation. Hope this helps!

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using your code.
The only way I got round it so far is to initialise the sdk each time login status is queried:

```
setInterval(function () {
                FB.init({
                  appId      : 'xxxx', // App ID
                  channelUrl : 'xxxx', // Channel File
                  status     : true, // check login status
                  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                  oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
                  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
                });
                FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        console.info("Session exists");
                    } else {
                        console.info("Session empty");
                    }
                });
            }, 10000);
```

In this way I always get the correct session status. If there's a more efficient way to do this please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the session always gets destroyed when the user logs out? Maybe it's just a var inside the session that changes if the users logs in or out....?

Comment: I can't tell when the user logs out so I don't know when to destroy the session. If FB.getLoginStatus was returning the correct status then I could destroy everything on my end.